# Comparing user input to values from an array

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question. It is a proof of concept bank login page.

The purpose is that if the input matches an entry in the array, you are allowed in. 
I have tried `object.equals` and the like but get I cannot compile correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JBLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args);
    {
         String username
         Scanner login = new Scanner(System.in);
         String [] database;
         database = new String[2];
         database[0] = "placeholderone";
         database[1] = "placeholdertwo";
         System.out.println(" Welcome To JavaBank!");
         System.out.println("Please Enter Your Username:");
         username = login.next();
         System.out.println("Welcome Back,  " + username);
         if (username.object.equals(database))
         {
             System.out.println("_____________");
         }
         else
         {
           System.out.println("Username Not Found.");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick fix: Remove the semicolon after `main(...) **;**`. Put a semicolon after `String username`.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted so heavily? Yes, the OP could have been clearer about the error messages that shown, but unlike 90% of the new posters why just want the codez, he or she actually wrote the code and is having a problem with it. A bit more friendliness towards newcomers please. Did you have a bad Christmas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare every element in the array `database` with `username`. You can do that using a loop.

Also, to call the `Object.equals` method on `username`, you just say: `username.equals(...)`. You shouldn't put `.object` in between.

```
boolean found = false;
for (int d = 0; d < database.length; d++) {
    if (database[d].equals(username)) {
        found = true;
    }
}

if (found) {
    System.out.println("_____________");
} else {
    System.out.println("Username Not Found.");
}
```

And as others have mentioned, you should also remove the semicolon from the end of the method declaration line:

```
public static void main(String [] args);
```

And you should put a semicolon behind the line that declares the String `username`:

```
String username;
```

Comment: *"Also, to call the `Object.equals` method on `username`, you just say: `username.equals(...)`"* ... this doesn't call `Object#equals` ;P.

Comment: @Tom It's an overridden method `String.equals` originally defined as `Object.equals` but that probably goes a bit too far.

Comment: That is right, it calls the overriden version, not `Object#equals`. And yes, it goes a bit too far :D.